# How to install packages in cirros OS

Tags: openstack

How to install a package in cirros image ?

I do not find any installer available in cirros image that comes along with devstack installation.

Comment: I think it's not available. try ubuntu.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As @Harikrishnan commented, cirros does not include a package manager. Cirros is mostly useful to verify that clouds are working correctly, that VMs are started correctly and things like networks, security groups and key pairs are functioning as expected.

If you want a linux VM with a package manager, you should look at a different distribution. The Ubuntu cloud image is a good place to start - https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/

Comment: I entered `microstack launch focal --name test` and got an error. I have the same issue as the OP. The only cirros works, e.g. `microstack launch cirros --name test`. What is the command to get a ubuntu image. As noted above I've tried focal, ubuntu, debian, etc... Nothing works.